# How can I better understand the impact of modern caching on algorithm performance?

Tags: performance, caching

I'm reading the following paper: http://www-db.in.tum.de/~leis/papers/ART.pdf and in it, they say in the abstract:

> Main memory capacities have grown up to a point where most databases
>   fit into RAM. For main-memory database systems, index structure
>   performance is a critical bottleneck. Traditional in-memory data
>   structures like balanced binary search trees are not efficient on
>   modern hardware, because they do not optimally utilize on-CPU caches.
>   Hash tables, also often used for main-memory indexes, are fast but
>   only support point queries.

How can I better understand this utilization of on-CPU caches and how it impacts the performance of particular data structures/algorithms?

Just somewhere to get started would be great because this sort of analysis is really opaque to me and I don't know where to go to start understanding.

Comment: Just from reading that blurb, i thnk they mean that they do not use RAM efficiently.

Comment: Have you read anything on typical cache sizes and latencies?  Accessing RAM on some modern systems can take over 100 clock cycles.  Accessing data that fits in the smaller cache or caches is a lot faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a really basic answer, as it would otherwise be extremely broad. I'm also not an expert on the subject (picking up bits and pieces to help understand how to optimize my hotspots better). But it might help you get started investigating this subject.

> <sub>***The topic reminds me of my university days when computer architecture
>   courses only taught about registers, DRAM, and disk, while glossing
>   over the CPU cache in between. The CPU cache is one of the most
>   dominant factors these days in performance.***</sub>

The memory of the computer is divided into a hierarchy ranging from the absolute biggest but slowest (disk) to absolute smallest but fastest (registers).

Below disk is DRAM which is still pretty slow. And above registers is the CPU cache which is pretty damned fast (especially the smallest L1 cache).

**Accessing One Node**

Now let's say you request to access memory in some form from some data structure, say a linked structure like a tree or linked list and we're just accessing one node.

<sub>***Note, I'm inverting the view of memory access for simplicity. Typically it begins with an instruction to load something into a register with the process working backwards and forwards, rather than merely forwards.***</sub>

**Virtual to Physical (DRAM)**

In this case, unless the memory is already mapped to physical memory, the operating system has to map a page from virtual memory to a physical address in DRAM (this is freaking slow, especially in the worst-case scenario where the page fault involves a disk access). This is often done in pretty hefty chunks (the machine grabs memory by the handful), like aligned 4-kilobyte chunks. So we end up grabbing a big old 4-kilobyte aligned chunk of memory just for this one node.

**DRAM to CPU Cache**

Now that this 4-kilobyte page is physically mapped, we still want to do something with the node (most instructions have to operate at the register level) so the computer moves it down through the CPU cache hierarchy (this is pretty slow). Typically all levels of CPU cache have the same cache-line size, like 64-byte cache lines on Intel.

To move the memory from DRAM into these CPU caches, we have to grab a chunk of cache-line-sized-and-aligned memory from DRAM and move it into the CPU cache. We might also have to evict some data already in various levels of the CPU cache hierarchy on the way, like the least recently used memory. So now we're grabbing a 64-byte aligned handful of memory for this node.

Maybe at this point, the cache line memory might look like this. Let's say the relevant node data is `42`, while the stuff in `???` is irrelevant memory surrounding it that's not part of our linked data structure.

[image]

**CPU Cache to Register**

Now we move the memory from CPU cache into a register (this occurs very quickly). And here we're still grabbing memory in sort of a handful, but a pretty small one. For example, we might grab a 64-bit aligned chunk of memory and move it into a general-purpose register. So we grab the memory around "42" here and move it into a register.

Finally we do some operations on the register and store the results, and the results often kind of work their way back up the memory hierarchy.

**Accessing One Other Node**

When we access the next node in the linked structure, we end up having to potentially do this all over again, just to read one little node's data. The contents of the cache line might look like this (with `22` being the node data of interest).

[image]

We can see potentially how much wasted effort the hardware and operating system are applying, moving big, aligned chunks of data from slower memory to faster memory only in order to access one little teeny bit of it prior to eviction.

And that's why little objects all allocated separately, as in the case of linked nodes or languages which can't represent user-defined types contiguously, aren't very cache or page-friendly. They tend to invoke a lot of page faults and cache misses as we traverse them, accessing their data. That is, unless they have help from a memory allocator which allocates these nodes in a more contiguous fashion (in which case the data or two or more nodes might be right next to each other and accessed together).

**Contiguity and Spatial Locality**

The most cache-friendly data structures tend to be based on contiguous arrays (it doesn't have to be one gigantic array, but perhaps arrays linked together, e.g., as is the case of an unrolled list). When we iterate through an array and access the first element, we might have to do the motions described above yet we might be able to get this once the memory is moved into a cache line:

[image]

Now we can iterate through the array and access all the elements while it's in the second-fastest form of memory on the machine, the L1 cache, simply moving data from L1 cache to register after the initial compulsory cache miss/page fault. If we start at `17`, we have the initial compulsory cache miss but all the subsequent elements in this cache line can then be accessed without repeating the motions above. This is extremely fast, and the computer can blaze through such data.

So that was what was meant by this part:

> *Traditional in-memory data structures like balanced binary search
>   trees are not efficient on modern hardware, because they do not
>   optimally utilize on-CPU caches.*

Note that it is possible to make linked structures like trees and linked lists substantially more cache-friendly than they would naturally be using a custom memory allocator, but they lack this inherent cache-friendliness at the basic data structure level.

Hash tables, on the other hand, tend to be contiguous table structures based on arrays. They might use chaining and linked bucket structures, but those are also easier to make cache-efficient with a little teeny bit of help from the custom allocator (far less than the tree due to the simpler, sequential access patterns within a hash bucket).

So anyway, that's a little brief overview on the subject, a bit oversimplified, but hopefully enough to help get started. If you want to understand this subject at a deeper level, keywords would be cache/memory efficiency/optimization and locality of reference.